# 'curson does not exist' asnswer from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-cursor

please your help...

object: a stored procedure whose ultimate purpose is writing flags in an specific column of a table. The flag location is decided based on the comparison of CURRENT values (i.e. in a 'current' row) and the values in the PRECEDING row.

General solution: using two cursors to scroll though the table.

It did work correctly using the standard structure, this is, cursors declared as :

```
cursor_evento_actual cursor for
        select * from public.camion_estado order by original_cam_id asc, calc_dt2 asc, original_num_post asc for update;
```

after that, I wanted the cursor declaration to accept different table names and colum names (taken from the procedure parameters), using EXECUTE. In order to do that I changed the way the cursor was declared: in the DECLARE section it went ...

```
cursor_evento_actual refcursor;
```

and in the BEGIN section it went...

```
open cursor_evento_actual for
        select * from public.camion_estado order by original_cam_id asc, calc_dt2 asc, original_num_post asc for update;
        move cursor_evento_actual;
        fetch cursor_evento_actual into vector_evento_actual;
```

Just the change described so far produced the error 'cursor does no exists'.

From what I see, it is not sintaxis... but I cannot find the problem

below, the procedure that works well and following, the procedure that doesn´t

the one that works, i.e., the one that correctly writes the flag 'repite' in the column 'aux_texto_1' of the selected table.

```
<<bloque_1>>
declare
        vector_evento_actual record;
        vector_evento_precedente record;
        cursor_evento_actual cursor for
        select * from public.camion_estado order by original_cam_id asc, calc_dt2 asc, original_num_post asc for update;
        cursor_evento_precedente cursor for
        select * from public.camion_estado order by original_cam_id asc, calc_dt2 asc, original_num_post asc;

begin
        update public.camion_estado
                set aux_texto_1 = DEFAULT; 
        open cursor_evento_actual;
        open cursor_evento_precedente;
        move cursor_evento_actual;
        fetch cursor_evento_actual into vector_evento_actual;
        fetch cursor_evento_precedente into vector_evento_precedente;
     while (found) loop
        if vector_evento_actual.calc_dt2 = vector_evento_precedente.calc_dt2 and vector_evento_actual.original_cam_id = vector_evento_precedente.original_cam_id then
        update public.camion_estado
                set aux_texto_1 = 'repite'
                where current of cursor_evento_actual;
        end if;
        fetch cursor_evento_actual into vector_evento_actual;
        fetch cursor_evento_precedente into vector_evento_precedente;
     end loop;
     close cursor_evento_actual;
     close cursor_evento_precedente;
end bloque_1 $$;
```

...the key part of the code is.

```
update public.camion_estado set aux_texto_1 = 'repite'
                where current of cursor_evento_actual;
```

after the changes in the way the cursos are declared, the coding looks like this:

(the RAISE NOTICE statements are there just for debugging)

```
declare
        vector_evento_actual record;
        vector_evento_precedente record;
        cursor_evento_actual refcursor;
        cursor_evento_precedente refcursor; 
begin
        update public.camion_estado
                set aux_texto_1 = DEFAULT; -- asegurar que no está escrita de antes 
        open cursor_evento_actual for
        select * from public.camion_estado order by original_cam_id asc, calc_dt2 asc, original_num_post asc for update;
        move cursor_evento_actual;
        fetch cursor_evento_actual into vector_evento_actual;
        
        open cursor_evento_precedente for
        select * from public.camion_estado order by original_cam_id asc, calc_dt2 asc, original_num_post asc;
        fetch cursor_evento_precedente into vector_evento_precedente;
        
        raise notice 'inicio Bloque 1b - tabla actual: %,  columna; % ', tabla_objeto, columna_objeto;

     while (found) loop
        if vector_evento_actual.calc_dt2 = vector_evento_precedente.calc_dt2 and vector_evento_actual.original_cam_id = vector_evento_precedente.original_cam_id then
        
        raise notice 'este es repetido %', vector_evento_actual.original_cam_id;
        execute 'update public.'||tabla_objeto||'
                set aux_texto_1 = '||quote_literal('repite')||'
                where current of cursor_evento_actual';
/*      
        update public.camion_estado
                set aux_texto_1 = 'repite'
                where current of cursor_evento_actual;
*/          
        end if;
        fetch cursor_evento_actual into vector_evento_actual;
        fetch cursor_evento_precedente into vector_evento_precedente;
     end loop;
     close cursor_evento_actual;
     close cursor_evento_precedente;
```

This the code reporting 'Cursor does not exist'

Comment: Off-topic: why do you use cursors? Updates in a loop is rather slow and could be done with a single update. Without a cursor

Comment: Frank, the reason: I'm self-taught, this is my first program in PostgreSQL and I'm learning while solving what I want to solve. I just need more fly hours... Thanks! your comment helps me a lot to know there afre better ways to learn about. I will try a loop...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `UPDATE ... WHERE CURRENT OF <cursor_name>`, you are referring the actual name of the cursor (portal), not to the name of the PL/pgSQL variable. Since you didn't specify that name, it was automatically generated by PostgreSQL. Name the cursor the same as the variable with

```
cursor_evento_actual refcursor := 'cursor_evento_actual';
```

Comment: Laurenz... thank you very much for your kind answer... I clearly understand what you mean... I'll apply the changes to the code